# Second await Statement Inside Function Never Runs

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, async-await

I'm trying to understand the async/await. I'm looking at the auto-generated code in AccountsController.cs. I'm trying to test it out on a console application:

```
private static async Task DoThis()
{
     MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext();
     UserManager<ApplicationUser> UM = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore(db));
     UserLoginInfo uli = new UserLoginInfo("Facebook", "CXco3k...access_token");

     ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
     user.UserName = "FB00001";

     IdentityResult r = await UM.CreateAsync(user);
     if (r.Succeeded)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(user.Id.ToString()); // This happens.
         r = await UM.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, uli); // Program sits here forever.

         if (r.Succeeded)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Login added succeeded.");
         }
         else
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Creation of login Failed: " + r.Errors.FirstOrDefault().ToString());
         }     
     }
}
```

The main function calling this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
      var res = AdministerFacebook(db);
      Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Maybe there's something I don't know/understand about "nested" awaits, or at least multiple awaits inside a function. Do I "clear" an await sort of like how I need to close a connection or something?

The program runs. I do get the new user Id thinking that the first await (to create the user account) was completed, and now, I call await `UM.AddLoginAsync` which doesn't seem to return.

If a replace all those `Console.WriteLine()`s with a `return "string";`, have the function return `Task<string>`, and in the main method code:

```
var doThisResult = DoThis();
Console.WriteLine(doThis.Result);
```

Program crashes and I get an AggregateException.

What am I missing? I mean, this is almost an exact copy of the VS auto-generated code except I hard-code the external credentials.

Comment: Post the details of the aggregate exception.  Look into the exception collection to get the details--there's likely really useful information in there telling you why...

Comment: Are you sure that the UM can be used outside ASP.NET?

Comment: Yes, we can use UM outside ASP.net. I got this working now. The real issue was UserLoginInfo.ProviderKey is NOT their access token, which is far greater than 128 characters. I was getting a db validation error because what I'm trying to save was way too long.